# Angular Universal express-engine server.js file size

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I'm adding Angular Universal `express-engine` to a newly created Angular CLI project (CLI version 7.3.8)

```sh
npx ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject <project-name>
```

Following the setup I run `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` to generate a production build and serve locally. It builds and runs fine, which was surprisingly simple The output to the `dist` folder is shown below:

[image: Build Output]

The issue is with the `server.js` file size, which is `5.25MB` (130k+ loc). This seems excessive to say the least. Is this the expected output file size (approx), or is the ssr build pulling in modules it shouldn't be?

Comment: Yup, similar file size

Comment: It contains the Universal template engine which sbasically simulates a web browser, HTTP requests, a DOM and the Angular core. So it's kind of big, but Node only loads this once, bootstraps it and keeps it in memory.

Comment: 300k lines. TTFB is non less than 6 seconds. I don't know if this delay is related to the server.js file size but 6 sec is unacceptable :(